# Cannot install on Plesk

Tags: magento2, php

So my Plesk default php version is 5.4 .
On my domain where i want to install Magento 2 ( last version ) I have changed the php version to php 7.0 but when i want to install Magento manually it doesn't recognise the version that i have choosed.

What may cause the problem ?

Comment: Are you installing it via url or command line?

Comment: have you tried restarting the php process via Plesk?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to use the path

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php ADDITIONAL_COMMAND_OPTIONS
```

... instead of just using "php ADDITIONAL_COMMAND_OPTIONS" over your command line.